# Converting an Optional to a List

Tags: java, java-stream, java-11

I want to collect an `Optional` into a `List`, so that I end up with a list with a single element, if the optional is present or an empty list if not.

They only way I came up with (in Java 11) is going through a Stream:

```
var maybe = Optional.of("Maybe");
var list = maybe.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I know, this should be rather efficient anyway, but I was wondering, if there is an easier way to convert the Optional into a List without using an intermediate Stream?

Comment: Nope, there is no easier way.

Comment: Yes. `List.of(maybe.get())`. Of course this assumes that there actually *is* a value present within the optional. Otherwise: `var list = maybe.isPresent() ? List.of(maybe.get()) : List.of()`. Easier? Perhaps not. Without an intermediate stream? Yes.

Comment: Would `List<String> strings = Optional.ofNullable("Maybe").<List<String>>map(ImmutableList::of).orElseGet(Collections::emptyList);` be fine enough?

Comment: I'd propose `List<String> maybeList = maybe.map(Collections::singletonList).orElse(Collections.emptyList());` as most idiomatic way...

Comment: I agree with @MCEmperor solution, it is better than using stream!

Comment: @MCEmperor's solution is the only one so far that doesn't introduce additional instances. In the other solutions, `.map()`, `.stream()`, `ImmutableList::of` and so on all create some unnecessary instances under the hood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the most idiomatic way would be to use `Optional.map`:

```
var maybe = Optional.of("Maybe");
var list = maybe.map(List::of).orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

Or, if you don't want to create an empty list that might end up being not used at the end:

```
var list = maybe.map(List::of).orElseGet(Collections::emptyList);
```

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I'll just post it as an answer.

`List.of(maybe.get())`. Of course this assumes that there actually *is* a value present within the optional. Otherwise: `var list = maybe.isPresent() ? List.of(maybe.get()) : List.of()`.

Is it easier? Perhaps not. Is it without an intermediate stream? Yes.